# ListView Not Updated from MVC model

Tags: android, listview, broadcastreceiver

I have a menu which when fired send an SMS and from the BroadCastReciever, the data is send to the model classes where the data is parsed and is set into the model attributes. The model class has a method which returns an ArrayList which is set to BaseAdapter?

My Problem is i need to fired the menu firstly, then send sms and does as above. The listview is not updated but if i click the menu again then only listview is visible.
What Am i doing wrong so that i need to fire my menu twice and is only listview being updated?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

yourAdapterObject= new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arrayList); listView.setAdapter(yourAdapterObject); listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE); ((MyAdapter)yourAdapterObject).notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

Seems your list doesn't know that new data is set when you update your BaseAdapter. If that is the case, you should call notifyDataSetChanged() in the adapter where you set its data if the data is not empty, or notifyDataSetInvalidated() if your data is empty.

Comment: I am following MVC model. So data model is in different package and activity in one package. I send an sms with a keyword say apple. The broadcastreciever recieves a string in the format 1=Apple=My Apple=2= Apple = Your's Apple. this information i passed to model class so that it parses and then returns an ArrayList<AppleModel>, And i do: apppleInfo = getArrayList<AppleModel>;appleAdapter= new AppleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), appleInfo); listView.setAdapter(appleAdapter);appleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: This works: yourAdapterObject= new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arrayList);
  listView.setAdapter(yourAdapterObject);
  listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
  ((MyAdapter)yourAdapterObject).notifyDataSetChanged();